Unable to download with wget
My environment is Ubuntu 24.04 running in AWS
Whenever I issue a WGET command to download files from my Google Drive to this instance it gives me a prompt (i.e. a greater than sign >), instead of downloading the file.
I believe this may have started after I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.
Prior to this things seem to have worked just fine.
Here a sample WGET command that I'm submitting
sudo wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zcbrZnN2U8Bl5y68kYVsjBc99tFxQzCG’ -O favicon.ico

Out of desperation and after much searching I decided to try CURL and the file downloaded with it shows az 0 size. :(
sudo curl -0 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zcbrZnN2U8Bl5y68kYVsjBc99tFxQzCG' -o favicon.ico

Any help would be much appreciated

The URL in your wget command isn't properly quoted (the closing character is a "smart" quote ...FxQzCG’ rather than a regular ASCII quote)

WOW! Thank you steeldriver Google Docs inserted the evil substitute for me and I didn't even notice it. It's working now.
